# Apache not getting access to virtual environment set up for Django project

Tags: django, apache, virtualenv

I created a virtualenv named '`pyapps`' and installed pinax and django in it.I've installed apache 2 and mod_wsgi.I created a directory named '`apache`' inside my django project(`testproject`) and put '`django.wsgi`' file inside that directory.Here is the content of my wsgi file:

```
import os
import sys

# put the Django project on sys.path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../")))

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'textpisodes.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Then I created a directory '`/check/www`' and put my project folder and `pyapps` folder inside '`/check/www`'.I chmoded 777 on `/check/www`.

Finally I created a virtual host,it's content is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail
    ServerName djangoserver

    WSGIDaemonProcess textpisodes user=rajat threads=10 python-path=/check/www
    WSGIProcessGroup textpisodes

    WSGIScriptAlias / /check/www/textpisodes/apache/django.wsgi
    <Directory /check/www/textpisodes/apache>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I try to access 'http://djangoserver',all I'm getting is `Internal Server Error`.Here are the contents of my apache log file.

```
[Thu Sep 13 18:39:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=4890): Target WSGI script '/check/www/textpisodes/apache/django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Sep 13 18:39:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=4890): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/check/www/textpisodes/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Thu Sep 13 18:39:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Sep 13 18:39:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/check/www/textpisodes/apache/django.wsgi", line 9, in <module>
[Thu Sep 13 18:39:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Thu Sep 13 18:39:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your virtual environment path so that apache/python can find modules there.

Either put this in your apache configuration (outside of `VirtualHost` entry)

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/me/virtualenv/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Or put it in the `sys.path` in your wsgi file.

Comment: Now I'm getting '`ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware pinax.apps.account.middleware: "cannot import name utils`'.Any Ideas?